# como evitar múltiplas chamadas de função na view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-views

Utilizando Angular, no meu controller tenho uma função que calcula a quantidade de itens filtrados.

Assim:

```
$scope.totalConferenciasRestantes = function () {

    return $scope.solicitacoes.data.filter(function (solicitacao) {
        return solicitacao.conferido == 0;
    }).length;
};
```

Na minha view, eu preciso exibir o valor dessa função repetidas vezes.  Porém tenho pra mim que chamar a função diversas vezes é uma péssima prática, já que você pode armazenar o valor uma vez numa varíavel e reusá-lo caso haja necessidade.

Exemplo:

```
var x = y();

inserir(x);

alert('o valor de x é ' + x);
```

No caso do Angular, tem como fazer isso na view?

Exemplo:

```
<div ng-if='totalConferenciasRestantes() > 0'>
    Falta conferir {{ totalConferenciasRestantes() }}!
</div>
```

No caso acima, teria como chamar na view `totalConferencaisRestantes` apenas uma vez?

Answer (score 4):

Por que não executar diretamente na view ?

No exemplo abaixo um bind na view é utilizado para:

- Filtrar a coleção `items`, removendo todos os itens marcados:
- Utilizar a coleção resultante e contar o número de membros.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {idade: 27, nome: 'Wallace', marcado: true},
    {idade: 28, nome: 'Wallace2', marcado: true},
    {idade: 29, nome: 'Wallace3', marcado: false},
    {idade: 30, nome: 'Wallace4', marcado: false},
  ]; 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.marcado"/>{{i}}
    </div>
    
    <br/>
    
    Total de itens não marcados: {{(items | filter: {marcado:false}).length }}
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa... dá pra fazer até `contagem_de_items  = (items | filter: {marcado: false}).length`